# How to filter the php multiple array with multiple keys and some array filter with min and max range

Tags: php, arrays, filter, key

I have an array with keys, I want to filter the array with multiple keys,

I want filter the array upload_wire ,exchange ,MarketCapFloat , KeyWordList and  ticker and etc Here the array

```
 [20] => Array
    (
        [serial] => 237
        [upload_wire] => iHub
        [ticker] => KPIFF
        [exchange] => OTC
        [price] => 0.073
        [displayPrice] => $0.073
        [MarketCapFloat] => 11587919.99
        [MarketCapString] => 11.588M
        [title] => Edgewater Wireless Prepares for New Board Member
        [TimeFound] => 11:19:27 PM EST
        [DateFound] => Apr 29, 2019
        [url] => https://ih.advfn.com/stock-market/USOTC/edgewater-wireless-systems-inc-qb-KPIFF/stock-news/79609163/edgewater-wireless-prepares-for-new-board-member
        [KeyWordsList] => {'Share': 31, 'Convert': 1, 'Customer': 1, 'Design': 2, '$': 20, 'Data': 23, 'Order': 7, 'Approve': 2, 'Right': 4, 'Phase': 1, 'Result': 10, 'Select': 7, 'Sign': 2, 'Patent': 1, 'Crypto': 5, 'Test': 8, 'Profit': 1, 'Provide': 4, 'Produce': 1, 'Make': 3, 'Enter': 4, 'Cannabis': 1, 'Partner': 1, 'Executive': 4, 'New': 61, 'Increase': 1, 'Research': 1, 'Made': 1, 'Meet': 3}
        [timestamp] => 1556597967
        [currentPrice] => 0
        [openPrice] => 0.07
        [previousClose] => 0.0751
        [netChange] => -0.0076
        [bid] => 0.06
        [bidSize] => 10000
        [ask] => 0.077
        [askSize] => 10000
        [marketTire] => D
        [cumulativeVolume] => 0
        [otc_CumulativeVolume] => 34200
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [serial] => 234
        [upload_wire] => iHub
        [ticker] => VRNT
        [exchange] => NASDAQ
        [price] => 60.87
        [displayPrice] => $60.87
        [MarketCapFloat] => 3973000000.0
        [MarketCapString] => 3.973B
        [title] => Edgewater Wireless Prepares for New Board Member
        [TimeFound] => 11:19:26 PM EST
        [DateFound] => Apr 29, 2019
        [url] => https://ih.advfn.com/stock-market/USOTC/edgewater-wireless-systems-inc-qb-KPIFF/stock-news/79609163/edgewater-wireless-prepares-for-new-board-member
        [KeyWordsList] => {'Share': 31, 'Convert': 1, 'Customer': 1, 'Design': 2, '$': 20, 'Data': 23, 'Order': 7, 'Approve': 2, 'Right': 4, 'Phase': 1, 'Result': 10, 'Select': 7, 'Sign': 2, 'Patent': 1, 'Crypto': 5, 'Test': 8, 'Profit': 1, 'Provide': 4, 'Produce': 1, 'Make': 3, 'Enter': 4, 'Cannabis': 1, 'Partner': 1, 'Executive': 4, 'New': 61, 'Increase': 1, 'Research': 1, 'Made': 1, 'Meet': 3}
        [timestamp] => 1556597966
        [currentPrice] => 0
        [openPrice] => 53.05
        [previousClose] => 45.59
        [netChange] => -0.32
        [bid] => 51
        [bidSize] => 200
        [ask] => 60
        [askSize] => 2
        [marketTire] => A
        [cumulativeVolume] => 632231
        [otc_CumulativeVolume] => 399840
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [serial] => 235
        [upload_wire] => iHub
        [ticker] => CBDD
        [exchange] => OTC
        [price] => 0.0008
        [displayPrice] => $0.0008
        [MarketCapFloat] => 3123430.4856
        [MarketCapString] => 3.123M
        [title] => Marijuana Stocks Big Announcement Coming Soon for 2019
        [TimeFound] => 11:19:26 PM EST
        [DateFound] => Apr 29, 2019
        [url] => https://ih.advfn.com/stock-market/USOTC/cbd-of-denver-inc-CBDD/stock-news/79590135/marijuana-stocks-big-announcement-coming-soon-for
        [KeyWordsList] => {'Share': 29, 'Convert': 1, 'Strong': 1, '$': 20, 'Data': 21, 'Order': 7, 'Right': 4, 'Phase': 1, 'Result': 9, 'Record': 2, 'Select': 7, 'Crypto': 5, 'Test': 8, 'Profit': 1, 'Provide': 2, 'Make': 3, 'Enter': 5, 'Cannabis': 8, 'Partner': 1, 'Buy': 1, 'New': 59, 'Increase': 2, 'Research': 1, 'Client': 1, 'Achieve': 1, 'Made': 2}
        [timestamp] => 1556597966
        [currentPrice] => 0
        [openPrice] => 0.0006
        [previousClose] => 0.0006
        [netChange] => -0.0001
        [bid] => 0.0005
        [bidSize] => 17437300
        [ask] => 0.0007
        [askSize] => 5361500
        [marketTire] => L
        [cumulativeVolume] => 0
        [otc_CumulativeVolume] => 1046900
    )
```

I Have tried with below code, Now I want to filter with Multiple keys for example, Exchange ,upload_wire, MarketCapFloat( min value of marketcapfloat to max value of marketcapfloat ie (1655072.6148 to 3973000000.0)) I want to filter Exchange as NYSE and NASDAQ , Upload_wire as AW and iHub

```
  $allowedVals = ['exchange'=> ["NYSE","NASDAQ"], 'upload_wire'=> ["AW","iHub"]];
  $result      = [];
  foreach ($nResult as $key => $value) 
  {
     foreach ($allowedVals as $key1 => $value1)
     {
         if (isset($value[$key1]) && count(array_intersect([$value[$key1]], $value1))) {
             $result[$key] = $value;
          }else{
            unset($result[$key]);
          }
      }
   }
```

By using above code at a time only one key is filtering, but I Want exchange,upload_wire & min of marketcapfloat to max of marketcapfloat with all these condition should satisfy the result should show out.

Expected Result:

```
 [21] => Array
    (
        [serial] => 234
        [upload_wire] => iHub
        [ticker] => VRNT
        [exchange] => NASDAQ
        [price] => 60.87
        [displayPrice] => $60.87
        [MarketCapFloat] => 3973000000.0
        [MarketCapString] => 3.973B
        [title] => Edgewater Wireless Prepares for New Board Member
        [TimeFound] => 11:19:26 PM EST
        [DateFound] => Apr 29, 2019
        [url] => https://ih.advfn.com/stock-market/USOTC/edgewater-wireless-systems-inc-qb-KPIFF/stock-news/79609163/edgewater-wireless-prepares-for-new-board-member
        [KeyWordsList] => {'Share': 31, 'Convert': 1, 'Customer': 1, 'Design': 2, '$': 20, 'Data': 23, 'Order': 7, 'Approve': 2, 'Right': 4, 'Phase': 1, 'Result': 10, 'Select': 7, 'Sign': 2, 'Patent': 1, 'Crypto': 5, 'Test': 8, 'Profit': 1, 'Provide': 4, 'Produce': 1, 'Make': 3, 'Enter': 4, 'Cannabis': 1, 'Partner': 1, 'Executive': 4, 'New': 61, 'Increase': 1, 'Research': 1, 'Made': 1, 'Meet': 3}
        [timestamp] => 1556597966
        [currentPrice] => 0
        [openPrice] => 53.05
        [previousClose] => 45.59
        [netChange] => -0.32
        [bid] => 51
        [bidSize] => 200
        [ask] => 60
        [askSize] => 2
        [marketTire] => A
        [cumulativeVolume] => 632231
        [otc_CumulativeVolume] => 399840
    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [serial] => 344
        [upload_wire] => iHub
        [ticker] => ANF
        [exchange] => NYSE
        [price] => 28.97
        [displayPrice] => $28.97
        [MarketCapFloat] => 1976000000.0
        [MarketCapString] => 1.976B
        [title] => Abercrombie & Fitch Introduces Limited-Edition Fierce Fragrance Bottle Featuring International Football Star Romelu Lukaku  NYSE:ANF
        [TimeFound] => 11:13:22 PM EST
        [DateFound] => Apr 29, 2019
        [url] => https://globenewswire.com/news-release/2019/04/29/1811281/0/en/Abercrombie-Fitch-Introduces-Limited-Edition-Fierce-Fragrance-Bottle-Featuring-International-Football-Star-Romelu-Lukaku.html
        [KeyWordsList] => {'Share': 8, 'Reveal': 1, 'Platform': 1, 'Customer': 1, 'Launch': 3, 'Transaction': 1, 'Design': 1, '$': 49, 'Data': 5, 'Right': 2, 'Team': 1, 'Operate': 1, 'Result': 1, 'Worldwide': 1, 'Select': 14, 'Success': 2, 'Exclusive': 1, 'Sign': 3, 'Positive': 1, 'Test': 1, 'Sell': 2, 'Sharing': 1, 'Produce': 1, 'Make': 2, 'Enter': 1, 'Introduce': 4, 'Partner': 1, 'Strength': 4, 'Promise': 1, 'Distribute': 2, 'New': 25, 'License': 2, 'Made': 2}
        [timestamp] => 1556597602
        [currentPrice] => 0
        [openPrice] => 14.75
        [previousClose] => 14.66
        [netChange] => 0.89
        [bid] => 14.83
        [bidSize] => 14
        [ask] => 17
        [askSize] => 33
        [marketTire] => A
        [cumulativeVolume] => 15
        [otc_CumulativeVolume] => 15
    )
```

Comment: @Rakesh Jakhar  Yes I want too filter MarketCapFloat with min and max values also, can you suggest me

Comment: below code we tried its working while all filter value present only. if any value is null its not working. we required both concept  1.  $allowedVals = ['exchange'=> ["NYSE","NASDAQ"], 'upload_wire'=> ["AW","iHub"], 'MarketCapFloat' => ['10000-49900000']];
  2. $allowedVals = ['exchange'=> ["NYSE","NASDAQ"], 'upload_wire'=> [""], 'MarketCapFloat' => ['10000-49900000']];

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code to the following by using `in_array`

```
$allowedVals = ['exchange'=> ["NYSE","NASDAQ"], 'upload_wire'=> ["AW","iHub"], 'MarketCapFloat' => ['10000-49900000']];
$result      = [];
$range       = explode('-',$allowedVals['MarketCapFloat'][0]);
foreach ($nResult as $key => $value) 
{
  in_array($value['exchange'], $allowedVals['exchange']) 
  &&
  in_array($value['upload_wire'], $allowedVals['upload_wire'])
  &&
  ($value['MarketCapFloat'] >= $range[0] && $value['MarketCapFloat'] <= $range[1])
  ? ($result[] = $value)
  : '';
}
```

Comment: Yes I want too filter MarketCapFloat with min and max values also, can you suggest me

Comment: @you can explain more, the solution is based on `exchage` and `upload_wire` indices

Comment: My array will be in the below format, here i need to filter for marketcapfloat with range of min:1655072.6148 max:3973000000.0 and have to filter with exchange values(NYSE) & upload_wire (iHub).Can you suggest me.

$allowedVals = ['exchange'=> ["NYSE","NASDAQ"], 'upload_wire'=> ["AW","iHub"], ['MarketCapFloat'] => ["1655072.6148-3973000000.0"]];

Comment: @David solution has been updated, you can change the range of `MarketCapFloat`

Comment: I have worked with the above code, Here MarketCapFloat is in string but in my code it will be in array. so i am not getting the excepted output. Can you suggest me...

Comment: @David code has been modified to work according to `MarketCapFloat` as array

Comment: above code is working perfectly Thank you for your guidance. but 
    1. if exchange alone is presented in array means i am getting empty array due to AND Condition 
    2. if exchange & upload_wire is presented in array means i am getting empty array due to AND Condition 
Exchange ,upload_wire and MarketCapFloat values are dynamic if we select the particular filter and more than a filter also we required both type of result according to selected filter. We tired but didn't get the expected result.